# Centrosymmetry in diffraction glasses

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, optics, symmetry, diffraction

I recently purchased quirky diffraction glasses and when looking at the sun or any source of light I noticed that there is ​centrosymmetry.
​​​​

What is this due to, perhaps the conservation of momentum?

Comment: what exactly do you observe to conclude on the central symmetry of the glasses?

Comment: https://i.redd.it/f1mw6ho3wmo11.jpg Something similar to this